# WordPress permissions error with admin account

Tags: plugins, admin, permissions

I have been assigned to manage a website that uses WordPress and hence have an admin account. It is hosted on a Linux machine. WordPress is not installed in the `/srv/http` directory. Instead, it is installed in a sub-directory (say `/srv/http/foo`). However, there is a catch - the person who manages the Linux machine (I'll refer to them as X) does not let me ssh into the machine (as it has 'confidential information'). As a result, I am forced to do everything using the WordPress menu and additional plugins. To manage files and directories without ssh, I have installed a plugin called [WP File Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-manager/).

I never had any troubles with the website. However, recently X and X's team have decided to 'revamp' their site (the `/srv/http` directory). Now, when I try to do anything on the site (say create an empty directory via WP File Manager) I get permission errors - but WP File Manager shows that I have Read and Write permissions.

I need to urgently update the website. But, obviously, I cannot do anything due to the permission errors. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get around this?

Talk to the administrator.

If you're supposed to have access to complete updates and you can't do your job, he's doing something incorrectly - don't compound the problem by trying to find a backdoor into the file system when you should be welcome at the front door.